# Mix ecto.create is failing

Tags: node.js, postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am following the guide from phoenix framework to create a simple application under windows 10 local machine. All goes well even after issuing the command mix ecto.create the application is being created but the at the end I am getting an error:

> the database hello_phoenix.repo couldn't be created:command timed out

By running mix phoenix.server I am getting further error

> Brunch 2+ requires node.js v4 or higher.....

Tried to upgrade with the command

> npm i -g brunch@1

but failed several times.

I can load and see the page of phoenix server but without css styles.
how can I fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your DB is up and running.

To see the css applied,

```
npm install --save babel-preset-es2015
```